# select address depending on Priority in c#

Tags: vb.net

I have a patient who has 3 types of address
1 home
2 Billing
3 Physical

1 If patient has home address only than it should set the value of home.

2 If patient has billing and home address it should check if it has home address if present it should still set to home.

3  If patient has billing  home and physical (all 3) address it should check if it has home address if present it should still set to home.

4 if patient has only billing and physical address it should check the records and if billing is present it should set to billing else to Physical

I tried below logic but it needs few more things:

```
                 If patientAddress.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each patAddress As taddress In patientAddress
                        If (patAddress.AddressType.Equals("Home")) Then
                            FinalpatAddress = patAddress.AddressFull
                            'Return FinalpatAddress
    
                        ElseIf (patAddress.AddressType.Equals("Physical")) Then
                            phyAddress = patAddress.AddressFull
                        ElseIf (patAddress.AddressType.Equals("billing")) Then
                            FinalpatAddress = patAddress.AddressFull
                        End If
                    Next
```

Comment: Why have you included "c#" in the subject?

Comment: Please detail what you mean by "... it needs few more things".

Comment: Sounds to me like you want `addresses.OrderBy(Function(x) x.AddressType.Replace("billing", "Invoicing")).First()` - why? Well you seem to want to pick the first address you come to, from left to right, in the list "Home","billing","Physical".. so if we replace billing with Invoicing then the list will be on alphabetic order and we just pick the first one